# Laravel 4 form data submit and update the database and also send an email with the help of post data

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form with 3 text fields and I have to submit that form so that I can retrieve the form post data and send mail to the recipients. But I need to store the post value in the variable and I can use these variables to update the database and as well as sending an email with this data.

I'm getting this error

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Routes.php:

```
<?php
    Route::get('mail,new',array('as' => 'new_mail' , 'uses' => 'sendmail@new' ));
    Route::post('formtest/submit','sendmail@create');
    Route::get('sendmail', function(){

        $data = array('detail' => 'email' );
        $body = 'body here';
        $recipients = 'abc@a.com,def@xyz.com';
        $subject = 'test mail';
        $date = new DateTime();
        $d = $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
        Mail::queue('emails.sendmail', $data, function($message)
        {
           $message->to('abc@ymail.com', 'Pradeep G')->subject('test --mail');
        });

        DB::table('sentmail')->insert(
            array('recipients' => $recipients, 'subject' => $subject, 'body'=>$body, 'created_at'=> $d, 'updated_at'=> $d )
        );
        return View::make('emails.sent');

    });
```

Here are the files

Routes.php
http://paste.laravel.com/LuO

Controller:
controllers/Sendmail.php
http://paste.laravel.com/LuN

views/home/ftest.blade.php
http://paste.laravel.com/LuM

Model : models/Sendmail.php
http://paste.laravel.com/LuQ

Answer (score 1):

Think you already fixed it but you have a typo in your controller. In the last line it says:

```
return Veiw::make('home.sendmail');
```

where `veiw` should be `view`.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part everything looks good except in your SendmailController, method post_create you have an error. The ";" should be outside of the last ")"

```
$new_mail = Sendmail::create(
    array(
        'recipients' => Input::get('toaddress'),
        'subject'    => Input::get('subject'),
        'body'       => Input::get('body')
    )
);
```

Are you getting the error on the posting of the form or just showing the form?

Comment: thanks for your reply.

I'm getting error when I submit the form. I updated the sendmail controller but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange is spot on with his answer. You are using restful methods so you need to change your form to 'method' => 'post'.

Answer (score 0):

You have your form as `"method" => "put"` - but your route is "post"

Either change `"method" => "post"`

Or change your route to

```
Route::put('formtest/submit','sendmail@create');
```

Edit: actually - you have to change the method to 'post' - so that your controller will work (as it is restful, and you are calling post_create);